# zsh: command not found - only works when I change path, but on restarting terminal, path changes back

Tags: bash, terminal, path, git-bash, bin

I have 4 files in my bin. Funnily, two of them work when I call them in the terminal - the other (newer) two don't.

My bin file looks like this: https://ibb.co/bsj00jG

When I type 'which chd-project' in terminal (chd-project is one of the bash scripts which works), it says /usr/local/bin/chd-project - however I can't find a local file on my Mac.

When I type which id-project (the bash script that can't be found), it just says id-project not found.

If I set `PATH=$HOME/bin`, I can then call the id-project file. However, whenever I restart my terminal, it resets again. This can sometimes be buggy, though, as later commands in that same bash script can sometimes not be found.

When I type `echo $PATH` I get `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`

However, like previously stated, I can call chd-project in my terminal (although it says usr/local/bin if i use 'which') but I can't call id-project.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your `PATH` variable is "reset" for every session you start. That's because the current session doesn't set environmental variables persistently. However, before a session is started it executes files that, for example, hold the value of `PATH`.

If you want to add this for every terminal you open, you should extend your path in your bash profile.

```sh
$ echo "export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin" >> $HOME/.bashrc
```

Please take not that you shouldn't overwrite your `PATH` variable, because it's used to find commands like `mv`, `cp`, etc.

EDIT:
I don't know Atom that well, but if you would open a regular (not an in-IDE) terminal it should work. It could be that Atom doesn't execute .bashrc for whatsoever reason. You could try to add it to to your profile.

```sh
$ echo "export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin" >> $HOME/.profile
```

Comment: But why might I not be able to find id-project when it is in usr/bin, since usr/bin is in my path variable?

Comment: In your question you're not talking about `$HOME/usr/bin`, but about `$HOME/bin`. If you have two of these directories you should add the other one as well. Also, you should never fully overwrite the `PATH` variable. Try running `export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin` in a terminal and execute `id-project` again. Does that work?

Comment: Hey! Yes that worked! But how can I make it so I don't have to use that export command everytime I want to execute id-project?

Comment: Good to read! :-) In my answer I'm talking about `.bashrc` that's being executed for (bash) sessions. If you add the export command at the end of that file it should work every time.

Comment: Hey, I ran $ echo "export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin" >> $HOME/.bashrc, but following that, I still can't run id-project.

When I type export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin at the start of opening terminal, however, I can.

Do I have to go into atom .bashrc and maybe put that command inside it as a file?